# Remove numbers from Dataframe name

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am referencing a dataframe name based on the file that I am ingesting. However, a file may have numbers in it. For example, a file name could be ***DocumentList20200101***.

I am trying to remove the numbers so that the dataframe name will be ***DocumentList***

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Having variables as the name of a dataframe isn't a good practice. Construct a dictionary of dataframes for this purpose.

Comment: Hi @mck. Hmm yes, it did not feel like a stable way of working. Thank you for your comment.